# How to store input line by line from an input file into variables

Tags: java

I am trying to store input of certain data types into variables and print them out into a output file but my code does not seem to work. If I enter the input through std in with System.in Scanner and print to stdout, my code will work. However, when I try what I have, I keep getting this:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at Queue.main(Queue.java:17)
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Queue {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

// open files
// takes input from test-input.txt
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("test-input.txt"));
// prints output to test-output.txt
PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("test-output.txt"));

//Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


while (input.hasNextLine()) {
  int teller = input.nextInt();
  String name = input.next();
  int simTime = input.nextInt();
  int transTime = input.nextInt();

  output.println(teller + " " + name + " " + simTime + " " + transTime);

}
// close files
input.close();
output.close();
}
}
```

My input file contains lines such as:

```
1 Jesse 2 9
2 Wilson 1 4
3 King 4 8
4 Andy 6 7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're never consuming the newline character after the transTime

```
int transTime = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine();
```

You could also consume the entire line at once, and then split it into types

Answer (score 0):

Try to make sure you are parsing a non empty line, it can happen if your file has extra empty lines, so i suggest do a check inside your `while` statement

```
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            final String line = input.nextLine().trim();
            if (line.isEmpty()) continue; // continue if line is empty
            String [] items = line.split("\\s+");
            int teller = Integer.parseInt(items[0]);
            String name = items[1];
            int simTime = Integer.parseInt(items[3]);
            int transTime = Integer.parseInt(items[3]);
            output.println(teller + " " + name + " " + simTime + " " + transTime);
        }
```